# Time efficiency of the hackerrank challenge `Merge Sort: Counting Inversions` using clojure

Tags: python, performance, clojure

I am doing the `hackerrank` challenge `Merge Sort: Counting Inversions` on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort .

Here is the Python2 code that passes all the test cases.

```
def mergeSortInversions(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr, 0
    else:
        a = arr[:(len(arr)/2)]
        b = arr[(len(arr)/2):]
        a, ai = mergeSortInversions(a)
        b, bi = mergeSortInversions(b)
        c = []
        i = 0
        j = 0
        inversions = 0 + ai + bi
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] <= b[j]:
            c.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            c.append(b[j])
            j += 1
            inversions += (len(a)-i)
    c += a[i:]
    c += b[j:]
    return c, inversions

# Complete the countInversions function below.
def countInversions(arr):
  _, ret = mergeSortInversions(arr)
  return ret
```

I am trying to implement the same logic in Clojure, but I cannot pass all the test cases due to `timeout`. Here is the code:

```
(defn merge-sort-inversion [sq]
  (let [len (count sq)]
   (if (= 1 len)
     [sq 0]
     (let [mid (quot len 2)
           [a ainv] (merge-sort-inversion (take mid sq))
           [b binv] (merge-sort-inversion (drop mid sq))
           lena (count a)
           lenb (count b)]
       (loop [c []
              i 0
              j 0
              inversions (+ ainv binv)]
         (if (and (< i lena)
                  (< j lenb))
           (let [ai (nth a i)
                 bj (nth b j)]
             (if (<= ai bj)
               (recur (conj c ai) (inc i) j inversions)
               (recur (conj c bj) i (inc j) (+ inversions (- (count a) i)))))
           [(concat c (drop i a) (drop j b)) inversions]))))))

(defn countInversions [v]
  (second (merge-sort-inversion v)))
```

I've passed several previous tight time constraint problems using Clojure, so I think there is no problem for using Clojure to do this. I believe this problem can be solved using Clojure, and there must be something not efficient in my Clojure code, but I cannot figure out where.

---

I updated the Clojure code, but still timeout on some testcases.
Thanks to , but I do not know how to make `subvec` `transient`.

```
(defn merge-sort-inversion [v]
  (let [len (count v)]
    (cond
      (= 1 len) [v 0]
      :else
      (let [mid      (quot len 2)
            [a ainv] (merge-sort-inversion (subvec v 0 mid))
            [b binv] (merge-sort-inversion (subvec v mid))
            lena     (count a)
            lenb     (count b)]
        (loop [c          []
               i          0
               j          0
               inversions (+ ainv binv)]
          (if (and (< i lena)
                   (< j lenb))
            (let [ai (get a i)
                  bj (get b j)]
              (if (<= ai bj)
                (recur (conj c ai) (inc i) j inversions)
                (recur (conj c bj) i (inc j) (+ inversions (- (count a) i)))))
            [(-> c
                 (into (drop i a))
                 (into (drop j b))) inversions]))))))
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are lazy lists, so `nth` is going to be expensive on them. It may end up being cheaper to just work with fully realized lists. You could also try making use of `transient`s.

Comment: Thank you @Carcigenicate

Comment: Fully realized lists will be just as bad. You want vectors instead, which offer fast indexed read/write access to a single element. The whole business of slicing the list made little sense in python anyway: the problem statement lends itself much more easily to iterating over a single fixed-sized list.

Comment: @amalloy Ya, poor wording. My bad. I meant vectors so you can get the near constant access.